# Regex Expression for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want regex that matches the following:

1. 1223.00
2. 1,223.11
3. 1,223,333.22
4. 1223333.21
5. 1.00
6. 20.00
7. 300.00

Comment: great, what have you tried..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex,

```
\d+(?:(?:,\d{3})+)?\.\d{2}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xN8eU3/2)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples you've given, you can use this.

```
[\d,\.]+
```

Comment: @derp Well I'm assuming that those examples appear in some longer text or are for validation of a string.

Comment: @derp Don't be ridiculous; we don't want to match empty strings. `.+` is obviously much more appropriate :-)